# Dynamics CRM 2013 multi-entity sub-grid

Tags: entity-relationship, dynamics-crm-2013, subgrid, picklist, multiple-entries

I'm a new comer to Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013 and I've self-learned in high-level to customise the CRM.

I have created a custom entity called "Project" which have two 1:N relationships to Accounts and Contacts. In create form for Project, instead of having two sub-grids for accounts and contacts can I create a single sub-grid which can have accounts and contacts as a single list? And also the user need to be able to add an account or a contact to the list as well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to create a sub-grid that contains different type of records (in your case accounts and contacts).

You still need to use 2 sub-grids.

Answer (score 0):

Guido is right. OOB no. I guess with a little stretch of imagination and little pixie dust you can. So what you need is a) Custom Entity called Project_Accounts_Contacts. Add 3 lookup fields to this entity 1) Project(Required) 2) Account (optional and c)Contact (Optional). This entity is maintained for creating this single list only at any given time. You will have to have workflows that takes care adding and removing Accounts and Contacts to this entity. Create subGrid based on this entity and you have a single list of Accounts and Contacts. You can do some realy fancy stuff with manipulating the FetchXML of the view used for this SubGrid. If this is what the customers want, this one way of accomplishing a composite subgrid.

Good luck.

Comment: Your approach is one of the tryouts I made, but that led to a dead end in terms of the CRM capabilities where I stuck in where I cannot extend the implementation for further integration. I think this is not the recommended or the intended way of implementation, but to go as two separate sub-grids. Thanks for the reply!